# If I credit miles from my United flights to Singapore, can I still use the United app + precheck?

Tags: loyalty-programs, united-airlines, singapore-airlines

I have not switched my frequent flyer program to Singapore Airlines because I enjoy using Precheck + the United app.

If I buy a United flight online and credit to Singapore Airlines program, can I still check-in with the app, use pre-check etc.?

Notably Singapore Airlines is not a member of Precheck, and I log into my United app with my United frequent flyer number. If I bought a United ticket without that United number, I worry I may lose Precheck access.

Comment: You always check-in with the operating carrier regardless of where you credit the miles.

Comment: I think my question boils down into how seamlessly this process works. The app may have a hard time, given that I login with my United Frequent Flyer number...

If you have experience with United, let me know!

Comment: @Johns-305 That's true at the check-in counter, but not necessarily in the app.

Comment: The flight can still be linked to your United Account.  Where the miles accrue is a separate, not always visible, option.  But also note, benefits and accrual are also separate to be sure to ask to only change the accrual program (if UA supports this which I do not know).

Comment: If you can't make this work another way, you could consider putting the UA account on the itinerary and then asking an agant at the airport to change it before you board.

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer, I don't know *exactly* how UA does this but...

The answer is 99% yes, provided the UA PNR (your itinerary), primary or linked, is associated with your MilagePlus account.  This is how it shows up at united.com and in the app.

Also, there's long been the ability to specify different programs for benefits and accrual.  But, different airlines have different support for this though I would expect UA to allow this.

You probably won't see the two options online for this.  They really don't want you separating them.  The only way to set this up ahead of time would be to call.

If the itinerary already shows in the app, you should be able to change only the accrual account at the Gate.